How to group by using aggregate()
The question is below.
Researchers have set five proficiency levels in CIL: Below Level 1, Level 1, Level 2, Level 3, and Level 4. For simplicity, we recode them as two levels combining Level 3 and 4 as "Proficient" and all other lower levels (Level 2 and below) as "Developing". Use PV1CIL and the cut score of 577 (577 included for "Proficient") to create a new dependent variable of CIL_LEVEL (1 for "Proficient" and 0 for "Developing"). Please make sure if you create this new variable correctly by using  aggregate with embedded range function.
The data name is CT_KOR.
 > CT_KOR$PV1CIL
   [1] 610.1726 536.0297 486.4944 510.7811 698.7426 489.2825 591.0807 566.0292 527.6944
  [10] 478.1921 582.3216 547.7692 571.0691 532.9718 374.6199 662.7491 514.7650 629.0674
  [19] 627.0129 625.7726 523.9097 485.5613 555.2949 625.6446 625.4544 579.6935 522.2717
  [28] 607.4198 590.7582 567.7674 613.3404 576.6527 628.6818 524.9084 616.9450 608.3879
  [37] 569.3843 589.6912 478.8122 545.1489 668.8271 682.7099 530.7808 608.3936 618.5848
  [46] 683.1247 671.6604 635.3076 719.2977 663.8203 614.3029 585.2294 634.8935 632.1665
  [55] 627.2535 614.2073 546.5247 588.7362 455.0541 630.4287 548.7369 569.1471 591.5804
  [64] 379.3007 655.7059 442.3343 703.0969 573.9475 517.4179 581.0366 608.9786 524.1069
  [73] 533.3098 507.8198 627.8082 631.7757 703.0099 556.6147 533.7735 435.9234 503.0598
  [82] 656.7491 610.1234 483.7502 385.3211 616.0607 539.4333 605.7844 348.6588 567.6139
  [91] 526.7432 452.4807 584.0824 504.4407 685.7394 645.7211 519.3448 577.5231 631.5154
 [100] 460.3575 571.1072 372.8615 418.4094 470.6738 326.9848 376.1307 476.4236 460.7276
 [109] 464.8018 265.9091 384.3027 421.4781 511.8900 392.1852 352.5679 527.5292 573.8367
 [118] 629.0386 520.6578 507.1929 415.9500 658.9268 424.9788 615.9770 603.2422 524.7137
 [127] 580.5351 568.3849 581.4110 432.8819 358.3111 592.2467 557.0001 596.5620 624.7964
 [136] 562.7968 551.2892 596.4786 586.1951 650.4873 521.6422 612.0697 582.7080 553.5536
 [145] 554.6864 712.5223 504.3991 574.3275 540.7888 513.2865 610.6803 683.5272 594.3095
 [154] 607.7757 697.5944 614.9488 537.2764 441.3007 612.6767 648.4753 573.1206 669.6481
 [163] 560.9017 383.6916 607.5759 614.0994 535.2829 498.7650 626.6462 459.6493 599.4698
 [172] 590.0448 499.5877 546.9769 631.6024 586.9019 603.5676 505.8720 539.7610 565.7867
 [181] 541.7483 698.8631 214.0698 407.3421 522.5834 341.9323 464.1518 536.8033 591.1985
 [190] 530.5338 602.5050 559.8515 576.4940 541.8526 486.5006 531.0415 501.7917 687.3182
 [199] 465.2342 365.8037 644.3875 587.3477 531.4102 623.3216 572.6078 592.6715 524.3041
 [208] 636.1258 595.7772 468.2215 309.9742 291.0744 345.1453 432.4905 431.6137 525.7699
 [217] 464.5111 667.1298 523.2919 632.3235 440.8505 586.1794 477.5876 505.8712 600.7812
 [226] 683.9547 462.3136 373.8445 338.3312 497.7788 637.2531 607.5671 512.1143 482.9765
 [235] 653.6729 496.9228 545.8161 599.5307 633.3563 534.6943 511.0465 590.8692 594.5772
 [244] 628.0557 601.7627 554.4089 634.2108 613.2450 594.6948 617.2501 653.5105 626.9157
 [253] 483.7834 543.3944 581.4319 637.2175 483.3355 441.6107 499.1648 337.3638 338.5623
 [262] 647.4014 317.2114 477.7369 547.9270 525.1443 652.5563 467.5695 356.2014 417.2018
 [271] 552.8672 554.2909 486.3138 493.6688 505.0836 597.2277 545.6250 483.8236 606.3112
 [280] 560.8840 620.1240 537.8582 403.7966 558.2255 492.4844 531.1171 344.9439 444.5986
 [289] 503.3509 509.1659 568.5809 642.0548 668.5075 471.4229 670.8706 599.9632 596.7061
 [298] 612.2471 518.5263 370.9307 660.7752 362.3088 646.4000 524.0676 550.4638 581.2960
 [307] 645.8874 558.8220 509.8675 533.9368 571.1732 706.4368 556.0088 622.0528 526.6369
 [316] 612.1288 610.0221 561.8771 655.1419 543.4548 493.0626 472.5344 707.9879 581.7706
 [325] 561.3700 647.6049 575.8710 571.6644 632.3675 556.0260 526.9691 378.8443 590.3157
 [334] 487.4770 739.5540 594.6709 495.2122 425.8457 546.6221 637.6905 504.3273 329.0046
 [343] 529.8330 454.5609 433.6484 517.4695 469.2410 373.3896 654.2946 633.8330 670.7710
 [352] 528.3070 592.0238 714.3752 608.4712 693.9635 517.0967 687.4010 557.9567 629.6972
 [361] 604.3159 629.3352 564.8151 594.7340 485.3810 593.0491 506.9151 510.3312 617.9392
 [370] 464.0122 617.8502 550.3765 491.5968 412.2156 436.4696 519.1878 524.3204 569.1781
 [379] 509.2561 553.4433 495.8182 712.3875 442.0752 551.9771 534.6656 583.4307 517.4090
 [388] 494.6815 488.4654 605.9946 510.6578 494.7884 375.2569 496.8701 508.8740 657.7985
 [397] 540.2819 651.6996 422.3496 536.5095 552.1974 407.3205 530.2077 576.8018 676.3231
 [406] 541.7036 554.8735 540.4270 588.5204 727.2967 628.7897 592.2194 671.3220 707.1966
 [415] 485.3446 673.7472 680.4779 594.3382 568.9618 631.6308 590.1269 455.3148 689.4375
 [424] 625.9905 499.3818 637.8866 527.0268 439.0485 514.6249 745.1192 505.1546 537.4362
 [433] 642.1925 609.7796 602.1587 550.3744 536.7035 527.0910 513.1427 567.9706 704.9052
 [442] 569.8309 531.5959 412.6795 596.6898 595.8808 518.5013 412.6355 497.5280 548.5859
 [451] 505.4673 574.7350 570.8707 603.2317 568.5441 392.7409 546.5554 567.5322 534.8740
 [460] 670.3600 440.2233 623.5253 543.5284 603.7673 523.2946 654.3232 514.2416 542.4837
 [469] 560.2479 530.7274 368.5643 574.2205 489.2742 392.4033 590.2572 585.3987 446.5354
 [478] 735.3303 526.0293 591.1479 437.9814 481.6034 593.6491 561.8535 605.4782 493.5615
 [487] 587.6825 579.8039 442.5309 470.7028 631.6225 326.0924 491.3062 724.5762 658.4295
 [496] 545.1836 583.3657 302.8177 593.7716 629.7934 575.7840 426.5096 570.5089 465.4861
 [505] 530.4368 408.6344 541.5439 529.3011 329.3407 556.3836 408.1099 538.8492 381.8463
 [514] 300.1247 566.9195 628.4352 513.5455 664.2645 545.8093 449.0567 684.6941 624.1112
 [523] 593.3947 684.6439 524.4125 538.4597 532.8545 634.0243 332.5007 466.6511 528.8399
 [532] 535.2424 498.6578 475.0555 400.6366 512.8722 669.4896 424.4301 498.6894 601.7947
 [541] 510.6482 440.2131 354.1841 493.8075 590.6427 641.9373 403.2258 524.5113 385.7828
 [550] 485.8268 498.3487 300.3041 622.8328 621.9232 529.5082 524.2689 498.1017 465.0673
 [559] 434.5204 593.3032 309.8972 524.8695 618.3695 705.6705 547.7182 343.4290 586.4730
 [568] 440.1994 580.7321 483.0616 418.9258 633.6992 681.3593 436.6994 410.5217 558.8730
 [577] 564.4813 352.2621 554.3032 443.4160 300.4667 549.3880 670.7755 670.8112 675.9812
 [586] 565.2126 452.6408 656.3288 460.6566 497.9571 482.4025 288.5071 562.6328 548.2367
 [595] 401.6052 548.0297 550.2048 634.1547 451.4506 205.3479 525.0772 597.5172 433.4256
 [604] 461.8033 373.1299 510.3819 345.9601 474.6677 390.9013 384.2334 409.8042 592.5206
 [613] 527.6902 606.2306 551.3911 574.3444 546.0834 559.1868 666.2265 618.8788 538.4193
 [622] 663.7334 632.0148 583.2458 608.7828 357.5803 683.4967 510.2015 597.3069 460.2933
 [631] 670.4713 656.1282 561.8084 702.9969 681.8683 551.4931 658.2867 651.5589 580.2509
 [640] 512.2999 348.2836 598.9734 533.6019 449.0267 348.7497 591.8666 571.4541 570.0749
 [649] 554.8738 715.5423 616.5714 624.9041 611.8861 471.2481 532.5227 500.9122 599.6075
 [658] 554.3853 447.1114 402.7847 497.3079 430.1130 523.2514 511.9647 230.3549 459.8427
 [667] 543.2000 394.8855 497.5001 350.5940 362.4497 414.5391 623.5342 649.0672 630.8329
 [676] 496.3026 549.7647 429.3879 549.6162 503.7263 403.8911 319.4957 305.3814 536.4746
 [685] 516.2697 691.8133 444.1847 521.6459 303.5204 623.1182 637.4966 481.4494 397.3149
 [694] 568.6503 542.8249 522.5746 573.3647 445.1616 472.2114 542.5459 369.8518 547.2766
 [703] 470.5085 488.2595 395.3229 773.6336 528.0459 422.1607 492.1754 560.4094 518.4545
 [712] 656.3358 512.5697 483.0450 636.7884 407.0311 470.2990 545.9634 685.3336 422.5806
 [721] 394.6296 571.8704 364.2055 586.7419 668.2336 420.7777 460.2786 549.1690 637.8717
 [730] 485.1395 639.4683 499.4613 643.1194 550.4720 479.4685 656.1778 413.9765 605.0390
 [739] 657.0538 607.3078 598.7892 468.7045 609.5553 532.5019 505.6835 567.4638 666.9330
 [748] 636.3258 555.4771 612.5618 536.1278 606.3381 472.0651 608.1485 661.9908 556.9476
 [757] 637.9076 549.9497 505.4512 502.9254 561.2122 726.6784 549.8313 590.5936 552.7611
 [766] 513.1281 581.2105 511.2493 564.8792 602.4473 614.2917 635.8458 573.4984 609.9184
 [775] 512.1127 395.1762 574.3437 493.7187 682.3807 377.1587 509.4152 642.5459 506.7608
 [784] 580.0008 557.5743 625.6982 565.0527 618.1601 643.4908 693.2171 607.3587 491.2058
 [793] 665.6092 591.2632 504.3844 445.2821 547.3844 594.8567 509.3527 549.7404 414.6339
 [802] 544.5781 604.6648 663.4548 639.2557 538.8879 514.4627 495.4890 557.5786 611.0298
 [811] 560.8141 591.2562 422.1747 560.8426 380.6070 499.6450 486.9992 483.9319 509.4972
 [820] 481.6197 560.0077 611.0568 565.0553 585.1861 670.6114 447.3882 660.6743 547.4261
 [829] 486.7865 384.0288 490.9424 483.6112 450.3489 379.9212 616.7521 442.8945 431.3132
 [838] 312.0358 519.4153 380.4219 545.9880 418.1550 590.4711 540.4183 523.6280 280.3552
 [847] 309.2470 432.6751 546.9604 623.0937 595.0230 512.0432 654.8731 614.8597 597.9931
 [856] 575.2531 601.6007 515.7683 598.0579 587.6038 446.3716 513.5403 530.0291 509.6453
 [865] 438.5816 341.2950 369.1405 559.6349 543.0690 547.5638 357.2809 509.6864 564.1927
 [874] 579.7998 608.0862 553.5102 571.6629 648.4707 407.7361 435.5789 515.4500 646.2092
 [883] 534.2466 654.3100 581.9988 576.1276 532.5529 524.6098 479.3209 547.9170 378.8833
 [892] 584.0840 560.9296 552.0179 412.4100 500.4508 604.9939 486.1859 365.4861 545.5607
 [901] 611.9878 553.6224 464.0422 533.8710 679.9812 355.0584 588.0829 554.0489 398.9246
 [910] 427.8454 440.1258 628.0580 422.3995 656.3239 612.0874 532.6908 522.8831 630.2063
 [919] 648.4412 542.8832 472.2348 503.3613 574.1035 647.7719 530.8216 523.8905 362.8608
 [928] 627.5681 497.5527 600.3700 472.2625 382.7398 345.7937 462.1713 596.0888 468.8220
 [937] 525.0912 528.8709 517.9851 583.4719 584.8182 328.7235 520.0649 529.0770 548.2714
 [946] 452.6109 611.7075 490.6138 618.3343 593.8566 521.9175 570.6815 446.6599 724.3289
 [955] 530.6449 553.2758 660.0523 812.6609 536.1668 574.2914 694.0791 583.4676 616.0094
 [964] 466.3206 596.8269 602.9528 618.4076 514.7611 543.0806 487.6603 475.3188 380.5811
 [973] 569.1942 504.6830 499.7571 367.4309 482.0945 515.2384 376.5055 467.3696 662.7557
 [982] 596.5207 427.3464 505.9552 410.7053 642.2937 586.4565 446.4301 363.0911 565.3702
 [991] 308.4431 603.0209 609.4712 607.9397 690.8757 558.4087 428.3958 458.4033 457.1218
[1000] 558.6880
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 1875 entries ]
attr(,"value.labels")
named numeric(0)

I found there is no five CIL level variables in CT_KOR.
So, I assign "Developing" and " Proficient" to CIL_LEVEL.
I don't know what to do after that.
CIL_LEVEL <- c("Developing", "Proficient")
Proficient <- CT_KOR$PV1CIL >= 577
Developing <- CT_KOR$PV1CIL < 577
aggregate(PV1CIL ~ CIL_LEVEL, data = CT_KOR, mean)

As expected, it doesn't work, appearing an error message.
Please help me.

Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please edit the question with the code you ran and the output of dput(CT_KOR). Or, if it is too big with the output of dput(head(CT_KOR, 20)).

As far as I understood, the question is asking to create a single variable called CIL_LEVEL and assign the values based on the condition. I would create the column CIL_LEVEL using the following code:
CT_KOR$CIL_LEVEL <- ifelse(CT_KOR$PV1CIL >= 577, 1, 0)

Then, if you want to verify that the variable is created correctly you should use:
aggregate(PV1CIL ~ CIL_LEVEL, data = CT_KOR, FUN = range)

